# Rails Figaro different location for application.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, figaro-ruby

I was wondering if it is possible to have the application.yml in a different location. I skipped through the source and found that if you use it over cli, you can actually specify '-p' to run against an arbitrary application.yml.

The lib/figaro/rails/application.rb suggests that the path in a rails environment is hardcoded to

```
::Rails.root.join("config", "application.yml")
```

Is it like this or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the issue could you say? because I find `config/application.yml` is the standard place to keep that file.

Answer (score 1):

I created a figaro.rb file in the `config/initializers` folder.  Then used the code below.

```
Figaro.application.path = (Rails.root.join('config', 'figaro_env.yml'))

Figaro.load
```

This allows you to put all your figaro enviroment variables in `config/figaro_env.yml`.  This technically loads figaro twice, but it works.